# Can we use two layouts together in wix RNN v2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want side menu in a particular screen in stack navigation.
How can i navigation.push to a screen in stack navigation having a side menu in react native navigation v2. As Navigation.push only takes component object.

```
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    stack: {
      id: 'App',
      children: [
        {
          component: {
            name: 'FormList',
            options: {
              topBar: {
                title: {
                  text: 'Forms'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
    }
  }
});
```

> I want to push to a screen in CreateForm which would have a sidemenu

```
const sidemenu = {
  sideMenu: {
      center: {
      component: {
        name: 'CreateForm',
          options: {
          topBar: {
            title: {
              text: 'Create Form'
            },
          },
        }
      },
    },
    right: {
      component: {
        name: 'CreateField',
          passProps: {
          text: ''
        },
      },
    },
  }
};
```